# Proving an inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

> If $x_{n+1}-\alpha=\frac{(x_{n}-\alpha)^2}{2x_{n}}$
>
> Show that for n >1,
> $$|{x_{n+1}-\alpha}|\le\frac{1}{2}|x_{n}-\alpha|$$

$|{x_{n+1}-\alpha}|=|\frac{(x_{n}-\alpha)^2}{2x_{n}}|=\frac{1}{2}|\frac{(x_{n}-\alpha)^2}{x_{n}}|=\frac{1}{2}|\frac{x_{n}^2-2x_{n}\alpha+\alpha^2}{x_{n}}|$
$=\frac{1}{2}|x_{n}-2\alpha+\frac{\alpha^2}{x_{n}}|$

I'm stuck at this point - don't know how to manipulate it further to reach the inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, such relation should hold only if you add the assumption $\alpha \geq 0$.
I suggest you to argue as follows: you want to prove that $$x_{n+1} - \alpha=\frac{(x_n - \alpha)^2}{2x_n}\leq \frac{|x_n-\alpha|}{2},$$
multiplying by $2x_n$, and dividing by $|x_n-\alpha|$, you find out that this is EQUIVALENT to prove that $$x_n - \alpha\leq x_n,$$
that is, $\alpha \geq 0$, bu that was our assumption, and so we are done.

You see that, since we got equivalent conditions to our claim, you actually need $\alpha \geq 0$. Does it seem clear?

Comment: Yes, it makes much more sense and $\alpha$ is greater than 0. My apologies for not mentioning it!

Comment: `multiplying by 2x_n` This requires the additional assumption that $x_n \gt 0$.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Actually it's @user1023 who forgot to mention it.